# ZF2: Why does partial() look in the Application module instead in Admin?

Tags: php, partial-views, zend-framework2

Simple question, but can't figure it out.

Why when calling `$this->partial()` in a view in Zend Framework 2 inside a view in the `Admin` module, it looks for the file in `Application` module??

Here's a stack:

```
include( '/.../module/Admin/view/admin/pages/index.phtml' )
include( '/.../module/Application/view/partials/pagination.phtml' )
```

Comment: in what part of the code are you calling the include function? the location of the views template should be set in the configuration of the module

Comment: It's standard behavior of ZF2 that allows to override views in another module. Make `Admin` module to be last in `application.config.php`, and its views will have higher priority.

Comment: Denis, please add it as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what this include stuff is that you do...

You have two ways to assign templates for partials. I always suggest going the fully qualified way, as this is the fastest way possible, too.

```
$this->partial('NAMESPACE / CONTROLLERNAME / ACTIONNAME', array(/** key value pairs*/));
```

When you only use `ACTIONNAME` instead of the fully qualified template name, then the renderer will look inside your current module and sarch for `actionname.phtml` in said module.

You have to use the fully qualified template name in order to load partials from another module.

As mentioned previously though, ALWAYS go fully qualified. It's a lot faster ;)